# Center map using multiple markers and google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

currently have a map drawn with two markers using the JS below, but when the map loads it does not center correctly when the markers are on specific locations... I am fairly sure this is a simple error but cannot spot it

```
[var marker1, marker2;
var poly, geodesicPoly;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 34, lng: -40.605}
  });

  map.controls\[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER\].push(
      document.getElementById('info'));

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: {lat: <?php echo $Lat1; ?>, lng: <?php echo $Long1; ?>}
  });

  marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: {lat: <?php echo $Lat2; ?>, lng: <?php echo $Long2; ?>}
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition());
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'position_changed', update);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'position_changed', update);

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
  });

  /*geodesicPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#CC0099',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    geodesic: true,
    map: map
  });*/

  update();
}

function update() {
  var path = \[marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()\];
  poly.setPath(path);
  geodesicPoly.setPath(path);
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path\[0\], path\[1\]);
  document.getElementById('heading').value = heading;
  document.getElementById('origin').value = path\[0\].toString();
  document.getElementById('destination').value = path\[1\].toString()https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help;
}]
```

Image: http://tinypic.com/r/29q01g4/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) constructor takes two [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects in a specific order: SouthWest, NorthEast corners.

> LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral, ne?:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)
>
> Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.

So this is not correct (unless the markers happen to be in the correct relation to each other):

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   marker1.getPosition(), 
   marker2.getPosition());
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

If you want to add two arbitrary positions to a google.maps.LatLngBounds, create an empty bounds, the extend it with the two positions:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker1.getPosition());
bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition())
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vmyx88ej/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker1, marker2;
var poly, geodesicPoly;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 34,
      lng: -40.605
    }
  });

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(
    document.getElementById('info'));

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: {
      lat: 40.7127837,
      lng: -74.0059413
    }
  });

  marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: {
      lat: 40.735657,
      lng: -74.1723667
    }
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  bounds.extend(marker1.getPosition());
  bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition())
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'position_changed', update);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'position_changed', update);

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
  });

  update();
}

function update() {
  var path = [marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()];
  poly.setPath(path);
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path[0], path[1]);
  document.getElementById('heading').value = heading;
  document.getElementById('origin').value = path[0].toString();
  document.getElementById('destination').value = path[1].toString();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<input id="heading" />
<input id="origin" />
<input id="destination" />
<div id="map"></div>
```